# My javascript code won't push elements to my array and I can't figure out why?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, push

So the basic idea behind my code is this.

There is a selection of 7 check boxes and a button that is supposed to process results when clicked.

If two boxes are checked the function should print the selection, if the number of checked boxes is less or greater than 2, then an alert displaying an error message should display.

In order to keep track of the number of checked boxes, I ran a loop equal to the number of check boxes, and every time `array[index] == true`, the value for that given check box should be added to an array called selections.

It seems like my code is failing to add elements to the array selections and I can't see why.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Side Dishes</legend>
  <h3>Pick two side dishes</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="1" value="French Fries">French Fries<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="2" value="Baked Potato">Baked Potato<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="3" value="Cole Slaw">Cole Slaw<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="4" value="Garden Salad">Garden Salad<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="5" value="Mixed Vegetables">Mix 
  Vegetables<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="6" value="Macaroni and Cheese">Macaroni 
  and Cheese<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="7" value="Applesauce">Applesauce<br />
  <input type ="button" value = "Enter my side dish selections" id="sideselect"/>
</fieldset>
```

```js
document.querySelector("#sideselect").addEventListener("click", validateSelection);

function validateSelection() {
  //Creates a list of check boxes to count true or false.
  var checkedSides = document.getElementsByName("sides");
  //Array to hold selected check boxes.
  var selections = [];
  console.log(checkedSides);
  console.log(checkedSides[1].value);

  for (var j = 0; j < checkedSides.length; j++) {
    //Inserts selected items into selections.
    if (checkedSides[j].check === true) {
      selections.push(checkedSides[j].value);
    }
  }

  console.log(selections);

  //Prints the first and second selected side to output if exactly 2 sides are selected.
  if (selections.length === 2) {
    document.querySelector("#side_one").textContent = selections[0];
    document.querySelector("#side_two").textContent = selections[1];
    //Tells the user they have selected too few items and clears selections.
  } else if (selections.length < 2) {
    alert("Please select at least 2 sides.");
    selections = [];
    //Tells the user they have selected too many items and clears selections. 
  } else if (selections.length > 2) {
    alert("Order is limited to 2 sides. Please adjust your selection.");
    selections = [];
  }
}
```

Comment: `checkedSides[j].check === true` should be `checkedSides[j].checked`. I recommend you switch to using TypeScript to catch these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: I would suggest understanding DOM elements and their properties is far more valuable than learning TypeScript - sure, TypeScript *may* help avoid such simple errors - but, then, what do you learn? Nothing

Comment: very complicated way for coding a form....

Comment: @Bravo Learning DOM element properties off-by-heart is not a good use of a programmer's time. Using a language like TypeScript with an IDE that will list the correct properties for you when prompted (IntelliSense, code-completion, etc) is a happy-medium.

Comment: @Dai - we differ in our opinions :p

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, declare counter and array on click call function to check all the elements using for loops.

if checked == true than add value or id in array.

Let me know if you have question.

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Side Dishes</legend>
        <h3>Pick two side dishes</h3>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="1" value="French Fries">French Fries<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="2" value="Baked Potato">Baked Potato<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="3" value="Cole Slaw">Cole Slaw<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="4" value="Garden Salad">Garden Salad<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="5" value="Mixed Vegetables">Mix 
        Vegetables<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="6" value="Macaroni and Cheese">Macaroni 
        and Cheese<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="7" value="Applesauce">Applesauce<br />
        <input type ="button"  value = "Enter my side dish selections" id="sideselect"/>
        </fieldset>
        <script>
            
            let sel =[];
            let counter=0;
            selection=()=>{
                
                for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                    let a = document.getElementById(i);
                    
                    if(a.checked ===true){
                        sel[counter] = a.value;
                        counter++;
                    }
                    
                }
                if(counter<3){
                alert("You Selected 2 or less Items ");
                }else{
                    console.log(sel);
                    
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("sideselect").addEventListener("click", selection);
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css Pseudo-classe selector `":checked"` to get only the checked inputs as a list of nodes using `.querySelectorAll` here is an example:

```js
document.querySelector("#sideselect").onclick = function() {
  let checkedSides = document.querySelectorAll("[name='sides']:checked");
  if(checkedSides.length > 2) {
    alert("Order is limited to 2 sides. Please adjust your selection.");
  }else if(checkedSides.length < 2) {
    alert("Please select at least 2 sides.");
  }else {
    // just for demonstration although there will be only two I like to use forEach :)
    checkedSides.forEach(checkedSide => console.log(checkedSide.value));
    // submit or do whatever with the data
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Side Dishes</legend>
  <h3>Pick two side dishes</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="1" value="French Fries">French Fries<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="2" value="Baked Potato">Baked Potato<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="3" value="Cole Slaw">Cole Slaw<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="4" value="Garden Salad">Garden Salad<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="5" value="Mixed Vegetables">Mix 
  Vegetables<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="6" value="Macaroni and Cheese">Macaroni 
  and Cheese<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="7" value="Applesauce">Applesauce<br />
  <input type ="button" value = "Enter my side dish selections" id="sideselect"/>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

the simpliest way...(?)

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']
  ;
myForm.onsubmit = evt =>
  {
  evt.preventDefault()  // disable submit
  
  let selections =      // get Selections
    [...myForm.sides].reduce((r,s)=>  
        {
        if (s.checked) r.push(s.value)
        return r
        },[])

  myForm.side_one.value = (selections.length===2) ? selections[0] : ''
  myForm.side_two.value = (selections.length===2) ? selections[1] : ''

  if (selections.length < 2) alert("Please select at least 2 sides.")
  if (selections.length > 2) alert("Order is limited to 2 sides. Please adjust your selection.")
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Side Dishes</legend>
    <h3>Pick two side dishes</h3>

    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="sides" value="French Fries"        > French Fries        </label><br>
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="sides" value="Baked Potato"        > Baked Potato        </label><br>
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="sides" value="Cole Slaw"           > Cole Slaw           </label><br>
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="sides" value="Garden Salad"        > Garden Salad        </label><br>
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="sides" value="Mixed Vegetables"    > Mix Vegetables      </label><br>
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="sides" value="Macaroni and Cheese" > Macaroni and Cheese </label><br>
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="sides" value="Applesauce"          > Applesauce          </label><br>
  </fieldset>

  <br>
  <button type="submit">Enter my side dish selections</button>
  <br>  <br>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>choices</legend>
    -- <input type="text" name="side_one" readonly> <br>
    -- <input type="text" name="side_two" readonly> <br>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, this was a very simple typo I had .check where I should have had .checked where my code is printed as [if (checkedSides[j].check === true)].